# How to conditionally disable client side

Tags: angular, express, angular-universal

I have a server-side rendered app (with transition) and I have a 404 page that I've put in a lazy module (so I don't increase loaded Javascript size).

This is working fine, but there is some flickering when the client side takes over, which I think is due to the JS chunk loading after the main chunk has finished loading.

Given this page only contains static links and one `routerLink`, the client side is not needed at all and I'm wondering if there's a way to disable the client side on certain URLs

**Edit:** as suggested in the comments I tried to conditionally bootstrap the application. I can't use the URL as a condition because the server responds 404 on the non-existing URL (there is no redirect at this point). So the most appropriated thing to use is the `TransferState` which i successfully set up on server side and it generates some output just before the closing `body` tag.

Unfortunately I didn't find any way to properly instantiate `TransferState` in `main.ts` because it's supposed to be imported via `BrowserTransferStateModule` and I see no possible way to import an Angular module in the `main.ts` file.

I tried to instantiate it directly with the `initTransferState` function but it appears it's not designed to be used outside the module since i get an error :

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/transfer_state' in 'G:\Documents\Projets\Myapp\Sources\master\frontend\src'
```

Any idea other than doing some dirty deserialization?

Comment: Maybe you could try not bootstrapping the app in your `main.ts` file, based on the url?

Comment: Your comment made me look into this file which I just discovered the purpose. This should work indeed, I will try it if there's no other built-in solution

Comment: I added some details in my question

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platform: any) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
            // use clientside stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to completely disable the client, not only a component

Comment: @GuerricP Did you figure out how to completely disable the client side rendering?

Comment: No I was never able to solve this